# How to decode an opencv Mat object sent from a c++ socket to android and display it to an imageview?

Tags: android, c++, sockets, opencv

I currently am able to send a Mat frame over a socket connection using opencv and c++. I would like to decode that frame and display it on an android device. Currently i am able to receive the mat data from the socket in android, but when i try to convert the image to a bitmap and display to to an  ImageView exceptions are thrown. I believe the problems lies within the buffer storing the image, i do not think it is big enough to store image so the conversion then fails because of the incomplete data.

CameraStream.cpp

```
void CameraStream::startStream(){
    /*************Socket Setup***********/
        int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    //Create a socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //If the return is less than 0, then the socket failed to create
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR opening socket" << endl;
    }
    //Initialize the buffer to all zeros
    memset((void*) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    //Setup the server address structure
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9000);
    //Bind the socket appropriately
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR on binding" << endl;
    }
    //Listen on the socket for an incoming connection
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    //Block until a client has connected to the server
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*) &clilen);
    //If the return is less than 0l, there is an error
    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR on accept" << endl;
        running = false;
    }
        /************************************/
    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);   // width pixels
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);   // height pixels
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN, 0);            // Enable auto gain etc.
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
    if (!Camera.open()) {
        cout<<"Error opening the camera"<<endl;
        running = false;
    }
    while(running){
        Camera.grab();
        Camera.retrieve(image);
        image = (image.reshape(0,1));
        int imgSize =  image.total()*image.elemSize();
        //capture->retrieve(frame,0);
        //Send_All(sockfd,frame.data,imgSize);
        n = write(newsockfd,image.data,imgSize);
        if(n<0){
            cout<<"error writing to socket\n";
            running = false;
        }
    }
    close(sockfd);
    Camera.release();
}
```

display.java

```
 private void startVideoStream(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(raspBotVideoSocket == null || raspBotVideoSocket.isClosed())
                        return;
                    if(image == null)
                        return;
                    //Toast.makeText(image.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];// = new byte[3160];
                    Mat imageToDisp;// = Mat.zeros(320,240, CvType.CV_8UC3);
                    while(isRunning()){
                        if(image == null)
                            return;
                        in.readFully(data);
                        //imageToDisp.put(0,0,data);

                        MatOfByte mob = new MatOfByte(data);
                        imageToDisp = Highgui.imdecode(mob, Highgui.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
                        final Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(320,240,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(imageToDisp,bm);
                        image.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ImageView i = (ImageView)image.findViewById(R.id.botCamera);
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                            }
                        });
                        //image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                    raspBotVideoSocket.close();
                }catch (IOException ex){

                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

the exception that is thrown

```
05-28 13:17:11.280 24057-24559/com.tidy_neutron E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 97
05-28 13:17:11.280 24057-24559/com.tidy_neutron E/org.opencv.android.Utils: nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
05-28 13:17:11.281 24057-24559/com.tidy_neutron E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8374
                                                                  Process: com.tidy_neutron, PID: 24057
                                                                  CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
                                                                  ]
                                                                      at org.opencv.android.Utils.nMatToBitmap2(Native Method)
                                                                      at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:123)
                                                                      at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:132)
                                                                      at com.tidy_neutron.RaspBotConnector$1.run(RaspBotConnector.java:106)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```